# Create a method for passing props to components in REACT

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is it possible to create a method that contains passing props that will be use for multiple components.

```
passingPropsMethod(){
        return(
           something={this.state.something}
           something2={this.state.something2}
        )
    }
```

Tried this code but has "Unreachable code detected".

What would be the best approach to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should return an object from the function instead:

```
passingPropsMethod() {
  return {
     something: this.state.something,
     something2: this.state.something2
  }
}
```

And pass it to your component like this:

```
<Component {...passsingPropsMethod()} />
```

or

```
const props = passsingPropsMethod()
<Component {...props} />
```

Comment: tried it but also has error  "this 'types' can only be used in a .ts file." on the method.

Comment: You have a syntax mistake. That is a vscode error. Somewhere in that file you accidentally used the keyword `type`, which is for typescript type declarations

Comment: It was indeed a syntax mistake but because I have used parenthesis instead of curly braces after return. I have added  "this." to `<Component {...this.passsingPropsMethod()} />` for having error of "passsingPropsMethod" is not defined. Now it is working. Thanks!